How to create org-mode 2xN table from two lists
I have a list that's supposed to be a column of data like this
A
B
C
...

and a second list like this that should match the first
1
2
3
...

for which I want to place in a 2xN table where A is beside 1, B is beside 2 etc.
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
...

How can I accomplish this in org-mode without entering everything manually?
Update
I should not have said "lists." I should have said I have a buffer with set N1 of lines and following set N2 of lines, each line needs to be in a single cell, e.g. lines N1 might be
A
B C D
E F
G
...

then N1 in table column 1 brought to match with N2 lines as column 2, e.g.,
| A     | 1 2      |
| B C D | 3 4 5    |
| E F   | 6        |
| G     | 7 8 9 10 |
| ...   | ...      |


What do you mean by a "list"? A file, an elisp list, something else?

Sorry see update.

Let's say you have the two lists in one buffer.
Select the first list (use C-spaceC-space if transient mode is off). Run org-table-create-or-convert-from-region by pressing C-c  |.
Now select the second list, run the same macro. You now have two tables:
| A |
| B |
| C |

| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Select the second table from the top left to the bottom right, but excluding the border. Positions of the point and mark shown below:
|p1 |
| 2 |
| 3m|

Run C-xrk (kill-rectangle). The second table is now empty.
Move to the end of the top row of the first table. Run C-xry (yank-rectangle).
| A | 1
| B | 2
| C | 3

Run C-cC-c (calls org-table-align when inside a table). Remove the empty table. Voilà!
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

If the data contain spaces, use C-uC-c| to create the tables. If the data contains spaces, commas, and tabs, you might need up to three C-u's: you'll be prompted for a regex to define the separator, ^ works to keep the lines together.

You can put the second column in place using C-x r k before using C-|, it does the right thing with spaces.

@rpluim: Are you sure? Even if there's a row in the middle that's longer than the first and last one?

As long as there are no spaces other than the one separating the entries, it's going to work fine: kill one rectangle, yank it next to the other one leaving enough spaces so that at least one space separates the entries, mark the whole region, do C-c | and you are done.

@NickD: But how do you kill a rectangle if the last line is shorter than a line in the middle?

Add enough spaces to make it as long as the longest entry. And also do the same before you yank (plus one space for separation).

@NickD: Yes, that's why I used C-c |: it does it for you.

Sorry, see update.

@147pm: Check the update, too ;-)

The grabbing of the second set of lines is troublesome with kill-rectangle. For a workaround I went to the final line and just added lots of extra spaces to accommodate any previous line longer than the last line. Otherwise, the rectangle is only as big as that last line, which chops off the lines too short.

@147pm: If you create a table for the second set of lines, it should pad all the lines for you.
